# Lost my dual boot after adding a new SSD

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, grub2, hard-drive, ssd

i was using both of windows and linux on HDD then i decided to add a new SSD and keep the HDD. After adding it, i migrated my windows to SSD and kept linux on HDD.
Now i have a problem that i can't choose the OS to launch anymore, so i have to change the boot sequence order from bios each time i want to change the OS.
PS: When booting from HDD the grub menu is still showing me windows between the options but i can't access to it.

Can you please tell how can i choose between windows and linux without changing the boot sequence order. Thank you.

Comment: You can use `sudo update-grub` to have grub update itself (*required if you've moved the location of windows as this tells grub to check for changes*)

Comment: Problem solved, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to find the Windows installation and update GRUB with the following commands:

```
sudo os-prober
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: I solved the problem by updating the Grub with grub-repair, thank you